# Add Indexes to columns in remote table - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, dblink

Am querying a remote database using DBLink. Now am wondering to speed up the query, how can i add indexes to few columns in the remote table.
Would appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendations around the same.

Comment: who owns the database?  you can't just add indexes as you please, unless you own the database.  

indexes are not always the answer.

Comment: +1 for specifying indexes are not always the answer. Where DB links are concerned there are many options for tuning queries, not all involve indexes.

Comment: John C, could you post more information about the query you're executing on the remote database and then you will get more options for improving the response time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER packages on the remote database to schedule a job, executing DDL.

**But consider this**, if Oracle throws an exception for DDL over databse links, there must be a good reason for it, right? You don't want anyone messing with your schema remotely over a database link. So instead, talk to the remote DBA and try to figure out solutions with him/her.

Answer (score 2):

it can't be done over the dblink (even if your dblink is using the owning schema) you will see

```
ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Materialized View in the remote database based in your query, add your prefered indexes to it, and then, if you need it, create a synonym for that materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

John, 
A good place to start would be the following Oracle documentation on "Tuning Distributed Queries".

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_appdev004.htm

Comment: One overriding thread is to get the remote DB to do as much work as you can on the remote data thereby only returning the bare minimum needed to the calling (local) database.

Answer (score 1):

you could create the indexes in the remote database and build up your query in a view form (in the remote database of course).
that way the remote database will complete the query using all the methods he got (like indexes) and bring you back only the wanted resultes.